# How can I dynamically build an http().get() url string using class parameter values of an object stored in the session

Tags: scala, session, gatling

Part of the main html response (from the "Go Home" execution) is a json blob.  Using the check() I have saved the json blob as a string in the session.  I then deserialized that json blob into a class/object, which I then stored in the session.  Now I need to build a url for a subsequent http().get(), using a value within the object from the deserialized json.

EDIT: Adding more code for clarity

How do I build the proper url in .resources(http().get())?

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocolBuilder

class MyAwesomeSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol:HttpProtocolBuilder = http
    .baseURL("http://my.awesome.site")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptHeader("*/*")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36")

  val scn:ScenarioBuilder = scenario("MyAwesomeSimulation")    
    .exec(http("Go Home")
    .get("/home")
    .check(regex("my awesome regex to extract json").saveAs("jsonBlob"))
    .resources(http("Home CSS")
      .get("/css/home_${state.version}.css")) // <- this is the part I need help with
  )
  .exec { session =>
    val state:SiteState = SiteState.parse(session.get("jsonBlob").as[String])
    session.set("state", state)
  }

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Here is the code for SiteState, if it matters

```
import com.google.gson.Gson

case class SiteState() {
  var version:String = ""
  var otherValuableData:Long = -1L
}

object SiteState {
  private val gson = new Gson

  def parse(data:String): SiteState = {
    gson.fromJson(data, classOf[SiteState])
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the exec().... getting called in your code? Please show whole workflow from top level till you get to the detailed code as stated up above.

Though honestly a simple way of doing it if you're hacking it together to use scala string interpolation s"whatever string you want $my_var". Don't know if there's a reason not to do that, which is why this is a comment lol.

Comment: I've added more code to the question, to provide some clarity.  I'm new to scala and gatling, but so far I've not been successful hacking together the string, as the _session_ object doesn't exist in the scope of the _get()_ call.